# Список переменных окружения virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv

Как получить список переменных окружения в virtualenv?

Comment: Эм, точно так же, как и без virtualenv?

Comment: А зачем вы дописываете название вашего окружения? Просто printenv

Comment: Да вы правы. Спасибо. вы напишите ответ?

Comment: Вряд ли, мне вопрос как-то не нравится ¯\\(°_o)/¯